# How to create and display a shakemap in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

OpenLayers is a library that develops tiled maps and shows heatmap on map, it also provides clustering. The examples are [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html).

I tried with this example and tried to customize it for Shakemap. Below is example of expected output.

[image: shakemap]

This above map is USGS map.

I used following function to customize the example given by OpenLayers.

```
   function get_gradient() {
    var gradient = {};
        //colors selection
        var colors = ["#FFFFFF", "#BFCCFF", "#A0E6FF", "#80FFFF", "#93FF7A", "#FFFF00", "#FFC800", "#FF9100", "#FF0000", "#c80000"];
       //some logic of selection of colors
     //  gradient[1] = colors[1];
        return colors;
        //return gradient; 
    }
```

I gave this as input to vector layer's gradient attribute

```
  var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
       source: new ol.source.Vector({
         url: 'data/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag5.kml',
         format: new ol.format.KML({
           extractStyles: false
         })
       }),
       blur: parseInt(blur.value, 10),
       radius: parseInt(radius.value, 10),
       //gradient : ["#FFFFFF", "#BFCCFF", "#A0E6FF", "#80FFFF", "#93FF7A", "#FFFF00", "#FFC800", "#FF9100", "#FF0000", "#c80000"] 
       gradient : get_gradient() //here
     });
```

I want some business logic that gives me idea of what filter should be applied to colors.

[image: heatmap]

This is done using OpenLayers 4.